# Scrape WSJ article and retrieve only text

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the text from a WSJ article (actually I need more than one article but for the time being I am only trying to scrape text from this one WSJ article). I use Python 3.x and I am using the code below:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.wsj.com/articles/SB120584797987545053'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0'}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')

tags = soup('p')
for tag in tags:
    print(tag.get_text() + '\n' + '\n')
```

I only get back the first two paragraphs from article text and then some text that refers to WSJ subscription. I already have bought a WSJ membership, so it might need to provide my credentials. Any idea how to enhance my existing code and retrieve all the available text?

Comment: There is no article data in the source code beyond the snippet, so you'll have to log in to retrieve the full text. You can use Selenium for that. Check [this project](https://github.com/philippe-heitzmann/NYSDA_WSJ_Web_Scraping_Project2) for example.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the whole website is loaded asynchronously and the content was not fully loaded? Try to use some time sleep or time sleep explicit, implicit etc.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer